# React with axios get function not hitting Flask backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I am working with ReactJS and axios to send a RESTful GET event to my backend written in Flask. I keep getting a `HTTP/1.1 404` error when I try to do this.

My ReactJS code is given below:

```
export default class BasicJS_wrapper extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.getJobs()
  }
  getJobs(){
    <h1>Test</h1>
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/v1/jobs/')
    .then((res) => { console.log(res); })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Node Jobs</h1>
      </div>
    )
}}

ReactDOM.render(<BasicJS_wrapper/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

My Flask code is given below:

```
@app.route("/api/v1/jobs")
def tester():
    return "query"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5002, debug=True)
```

The error I get in the Flask console is shown below:

```
"GET /api/v1/jobs/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you try adding a trailing slash in `@app.route("/api/v1/jobs")`? And conversely, if that didn't work, removing the trailing slash from `axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/v1/jobs/')`?

Comment: should be @app.route("/api/v1/jobs/"), slash at the end

Comment: The @app.route("api/v1/jobs/") trailing slash did the trick, changed from 404 to 200. But I am still not able to view the output in console.log.

Comment: can you show your `package.json` , is your app running on the same port ? i.e: `5002` ?